# Forcing Apache 2.4 to cache files with query string using mod_cache without expires

Tags: freebsd, mod-proxy, apache-2.4, mod-cache

I need to get mod_cache_disk to cache a site containing query strings. The issue is that it's a vendor product on IIS that we're trying to cache through mod_proxy and it does not contain expires headers. I realize this issue violates several RFCs and that's why apache does not do it by default.

Is there a way to force apache 2.4.x to cache with query string and no expires header?

This configuration will cache, but of course without honoring ? it caches the wrong content for most items.

```
CacheEnable disk https://
CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot /var/cache/mod_proxy/
CacheDirLevels 4
CacheDirLength 5
CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
CacheIgnoreHeaders None
CacheMaxFileSize 100000000
CacheMinFileSize 1
CacheMaxExpire 1209600
CacheDefaultExpire 3600
CacheIgnoreQueryString On
CacheStoreNoStore On
CacheStorePrivate On
```

If I change CacheIgnoreQueryString to Off it will start emitting errors about the expires header.

AH00768: cache: /view.image?Id=1114 not cached. Reason: Query string present but no explicit expiration time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/421488/189656) the only way to do this is to let Apache see the headers it wants (Expires, which you stated, and, apparently also Last-Modified).

The poster of that answer suggested writing a filter on the application side, but since yours is a vendor product, that may not be possible. Is there a chance to add it directly in IIS? Otherwise, you might have luck with a double proxy setup: use one proxy to add the headers (but not cache), and proxy *that* from Apache (taking the headers and caching).

Answer (score 0):

that's my solution

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
    CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
    <IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
        CacheRoot D:\\apache_cache
        CacheEnable disk /
        CacheDirLevels 1
        CacheDirLength 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and from the backend side add header

```
Cache-Control:s-maxage=1200
```

s-maxage - for proxy caches and CDNs

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution would be to strip the query string off before it reaches `mod_cache`.

And the most obvious module for that would be `mod_rewrite`.

But that [won't work](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21935#c2), because `mod_cache` started using purposefully the [unchanged version of the query-string in 2006](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-cvs/200611.mbox/%3C20061118221734.635EB1A9846@eris.apache.org%3E).

Comment: How is this the "most obvious" solution, if it won't work?